# How do I define password from bash functions using expect

Tags: bash, expect

I want to be able to take some command `wget http://host/password.txt` and read it into a variable into expect so that I can use it in SSH script.

Here's some incorrect code of what it should do:

```
set password "wget -O tmp http://host/password.txt && cat tmp";
spawn ssh 111.222.333.444;
send "$password\r";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can use expect within bash:

```
wget -O tmp http://host/password.txt
password=$(<tmp)
login="root"
IP="localhost:8000"

expect_sh=$(expect -c "
spawn ssh $login@$IP
expect \"password:\"
send \"$password\r\"
expect \"#\"
send \"cd /var\r\"
")

echo "$expect_sh"
```

However, unless you have a specific reason to do this, [using ssh keys](http://paulkeck.com/ssh/) is the preferred method.

Comment: Yes, I've seen those examples, however, is there a way to use bash inside expect? The reason why is because my expect script does more than just logging into a SSH server and it does error handling. So I'd want to be able to re-wget the password.txt upon some condition (e.g. server is going down because of restart).

Comment: @Hengjie, you could spawn a bash process, but that's increasing the complexity of your expect script. You could also `export` the bash variables and then, in expect, access them from the `env` global array.

Comment: @glennjackman do you know if the `env` array will be updated during the execution of the expect script? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you can save the password to variable like this:

> wget -O tmp `http://host/password.txt`
>   password=$(cat tmp);

but you cannot use it over ssh password , since ssh password is read by terminal input as an interactive action.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using the [/usr/bin/expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) binary to do this which does allow me to interact with SSH and send the password.